# how to group by first letter of text

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query in MySQL:

```
select val,count(val)
from ....
where ...
group by val
```

It gives:

```
val   count
CE3    4
CE5    1
A3     12
BRICK4  5
BRICK2  2
```

I want to show only the row with the highest count per first letter.
Which means all `val` starting with `A` are one group, all `val` starting with `B` are another group etc...

The expected result is:

```
val   count
CE3    4     /  CE3  CE5  are in group C , CE3 has higher count
A3     12    /  A3 is the only one in group A
BRICK4  5    / BRICK4  BRICK2  are in group B, BRICK4   has higher count
```

How can I do that?

**Edit:**
what I thought to do is to create a temp column in a query that will represent the group something like:

```
val   count  group
CE3    4      C
CE5    1      C
A3     12     A
BRICK4  5     B
BRICK2  2     B
```

and then search for the row with the highest count value per group.
But i'm not sure this is the best approach

Comment: look at [LEFT()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-left-function.php)

Comment: why would you to show a count for the substring of the first letter, then label it as the entire val? That doesn't really make any sense

Comment: also you sample output doesn't match the requirement you told us

Comment: @SaggingRufus actually it does. It is a little trickier.

Comment: @SaggingRufus If you'll notice what I want is only to filter the results of my query... I want one result per group with the highest count. Basically its to show the most common val per group.

Comment: @avi ok gotcha I miss interpreted what you were asking I though you wanted to count everything that starts with A then label it as ABC, rather than what you actually asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select
    val
    ,MAX(count) as count
    ,left(val,1) as first_letter
from (
    select
        val
        ,count(val) as count
    from tbl
    group by val
) a
group by left(val, 1);
```

First get `count` per `val` and from this result get the `MAX`count grouping by first letter

**UPDATE**: (thx to *Vamsi Prabhala* for pointing it out that my first solution wasn't the best one)

After get the `count` per `val`, I used a variable to redo the `ROW_NUMBER()` functionality (from MS-SQL) and select the first row from result, ordered by `first_letter` and `count` desc

---

```
select val, count, first_letter from (
  select
     @i:=CASE
          WHEN @first_letter = first_letter THEN @i + 1
          ELSE 1
     END as rn
     ,@first_letter:= a.first_letter as First_letter
     ,a.val
     ,a.count
  from (
      select
          val
          ,count(val) as count
          ,left(val,1) as first_letter
      from tbl
      group by val
  )a, (select @i:=0) b
  order by First_letter, count desc
  ) c
where rn = 1
```

Comment: this `group by` wouldn't usually work in most other dbms' other than MySQL.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala then its a good thing the question is tagged with mysql

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala I wrote that my question is about MySQL.

Comment: Even in MySQL..the `val` would be randomly chosen and it wouldn't always be the one with `max` count...i suggest you to try it and check.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala can you give an example?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala how would you fix it then?

Comment: my solution would give you reliable results.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with variables to rank the rows based on counts.

```
select val,val_cnt 
from (
select val,val_cnt,@rn:=case when @prev=left(val,1) then @rn+1 else 1 end as rnum,
@prev:=left(val,1)
from (select val,count(val) as val_cnt
      from ....
      where ...
      group by val
     ) t
cross join (select @rn:=0,@prev:='') r
order by left(val,1),val_cnt desc,val --added val to order by to break ties 
) t 
where rnum=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's what you want :

Let's get the max from each starting letter :

```
 SELECT LEFT(val, 1) as l_val, MAX(count_val)
 FROM (
   select val,count(val) as count_val
   from ....
   where ...
   group by val
 ) t
 GROUP BY l_val
```

THEN as you want the val to appear :

```
SELECT t2.val, t1.max_val
FROM (
 SELECT LEFT(val, 1) as l_val, MAX(count_val) as max_val
 FROM (
   select val,count(val) as count_val
   from ....
   where ...
   group by val
 ) t
 GROUP BY l_val) t1
 INNER JOIN `YOUR_table` t2 ON LEFT(t2.val,1) = t1.l_val
```